# Cycle through synonyms of a selected word in AHK

Tags: windows, automation, autohotkey

Here is what I want to do:

Let's say I have a sentence in an arbitrary text editor:

> Tim is a happy guy.

If my cursor is placed right at the end of a word - e. g. *"happy"*, and I then press a certain hotkey, the script should look if there is pool of synonyms containing the word *"happy"*, and if there is, replace it by the next synonym in the list.

So you could cycle through all synonyms by repeatedly pressing the hotkey.

The synonym lists should be within the script, e.g.:

```
(
happy
cheerful
jolly
merry
lively
)
```

I've found [this post](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/95019-replace-typed-word-with-a-random-synonym/)  where something similar is done. (There, one specific word always gets replaced by a random synonym)

**Questions:**

- Is there a script that already does this?
- If not - how would you do that?

(I should also mention that I'm quite new to AHK.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use something like this:

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force

synonyms=
(
happy,cheerful,jolly,merry,lively
unhappy,sad,down,depressed
calm,quiet,peaceful,still
; ...
)

$F1::
synonyms_found := "" ; empty this variable (erase its content)
Menu, Replace Synonym, Add
Menu, Replace Synonym, deleteAll ; empty this menu
ClipSaved := ClipboardAll ; save the entire clipboard to the variable ClipSaved
clipboard := "" ; empty the clipboard (start off empty to allow ClipWait to detect when the text has arrived)
Send ^+{Left} ; select the word left to cursor
Sleep, 50
Send ^c ; copy the selected word
ClipWait 0.5 ; wait 0.5 seconds for the clipboard to contain data
if (ErrorLevel) ; If ErrorLevel, clipwait found no data on the clipboard within 0.5 seconds
{
    MsgBox, No word selected
    clipboard := ClipSaved ; restore original clipboard
    return ; don't go any further
}
; otherwise:
Loop, Parse, synonyms, `n,`r ; retrieve each line from the synonyms, one at a time
{   
    If InStr(A_LoopField, clipboard) ; if the retrieved line contains the word copied
    {       
        synonyms_found .= A_LoopField . "," ; concatenate (join) the retrieved lines into a single variable
        Loop, Parse, synonyms_found, `, ; retrieve each word from the retrieved lines
            Menu, Replace Synonym, Add, %A_LoopField%, Replace_Synonym  ; create a menu of the synonym words
    }
}
If (synonyms_found != "") ; if this variable isn't empty
    Menu, Replace Synonym, Show
else
    MsgBox, No synonyms found for "%clipboard%"
Sleep, 300
clipboard := ClipSaved ; restore original clipboard
return

; select a menu item to replace the selected word:
Replace_Synonym:
SendInput, %A_ThisMenuItem%
return
```

Comment: The idea with the menu is even better, thank you very much!